# Oracle Trigger Doesn't Update

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I have run this code to create this trigger because I need to update TABLE2 with the UID value of rows with the same sequence number inserted into TABLE1.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_NAME BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE1 FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  seq NUMBER(10);
  uid CHAR(36);
  BEGIN
    seq  := :new.SEQ;
    uid  := :new.UID;
    UPDATE TABLE2 SET TABLE2.UID = uid WHERE TABLE2.SEQ = seq;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('UPDATE TABLE2 SET UID = '||uid||' WHERE SEQ = '||seq||';');
END;
```

The trigger seems to create without a problem so I

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
```

and then

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (SEQ, UID) VALUES (47, 'TEST_VALUE');
```

and get the expected output

```
UPDATE TABLE2 SET UID = TEST_VALUE                            WHERE SEQ = 47;
```

So, the correct values seem to be going into the trigger. Then I check TABLE2 by running

```
SELECT SEQ,UID FROM TABLE2 WHERE SEQ = 47;
```

and get

```
SEQ UID                                
--- ------------------------------------
47                                    
1 row selected.
```

Does anybody see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Did you make a ROLLBACK, i.e. did you forget to COMMIT?

Comment: It's the same session. I have tried running a COMMIT afterwards though, just to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is really your code, the statement

```
UPDATE TABLE2 SET TABLE2.UID = uid WHERE TABLE2.SEQ = seq;
```

resolves `seq` and `uid` to the columns in `table2` rather than the local variable of the same name.  So you're updating every row in `table2` and setting the `uid` value to the existing value.  The simplest solution is to rename your local variables so that they don't conflict with any identifiers.  I'd use a `l_` prefix

```
  DECLARE
    l_seq NUMBER(10);
    l_uid CHAR(36);
  BEGIN
    l_seq := :new.SEQ;
    l_uid := :new.UID;
    UPDATE TABLE2 SET TABLE2.UID = l_uid WHERE TABLE2.SEQ = l_seq ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('UPDATE TABLE2 SET UID = '||l_uid ||' WHERE SEQ = '||l_seq ||';');
  END;
```

I believe you could also qualify the `seq` and `uid` with the trigger name to force those references to be to the local variable.  Never tried that with a trigger but it should work the same way that it does for other named PL/SQL blocks like procedures and functions.  But I'd much rather rename my local variables.